# Can't make cookies expire

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to make a cookie expire, I've saw the code that does it, and I've done it already.

So, what I've done already was making the expire date like this `time() - 10` this would make the cookie time limit expire immediately, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
$number_of_days = 30 ; 
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * $number_of_days ; 
setcookie( "userlogin", $user_hash, $date_of_expiry, "/" ) ;
```

Comment: Could you share some of the code that actually does the expiry?

Comment: If you show the code that sets and expires the cookie we can help. without that, we are just guessing what is wrong with your secret code.

Comment: `$number_of_days = 30 ;    
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * $number_of_days ;    
setcookie( "userlogin", $user_hash, $date_of_expiry, "/" ) ;   `

this is where I set the cookie, and this is what I'm doing to make it expire:

`$date_of_expiry = time() -10;
setcookie('userlogin', '', $date_of_expiry);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()-3600);
```

If that does not work, you have any output before, you have to call it **before** any `echo` or html output. Otherwise the headers will be already sent and you can't change any cookie information.

Comment: I've done it, but it doesn't make it expire like I need

Comment: How does it make it expire then?

Comment: Do you have any output BEFORE `setcookie` ?

Comment: also, why do you use a cookie and not a php sessionid? It would be much cleaner (and probably more secure)

Comment: yes, i'm writing it between my html code, can it be the error?

Comment: Yeah, because cookies are sent in the header .. if you output any html the header will be already sent and you can't modify any cookie. set_cookie **always** has to be before any output